# Does every person have to go through grave?

Tags: day-of-judgement

Every person who dies would have to go through grave and then other. He would get grave punishment or happiness and then pass throw it at judgment day.

My question now,I know that judgment day would come an instant while everyone is be busy working as they used to but then they would start running here and there to save themselves and die eventually.

**I simply want to ask, would those people *"who would die at the time of judgment day"* pass through grave too? ?**

Answer (score -1):

Ok If You Want A Simple Answer Then It Is Yes,
But Here's Detail.

Acc/ To Islam Human Has Some Stages That He Definitely Will Face,

1. Life On Earth
2. Life In Grave
3. And The Life Hereafter, The Judgment Day.

The Formula For A Happy Time For  Judgment Day Is Very Simple.
Live The Life As The Muhammad ( صلی اللہ تعالی علیہ وسلم )
Has Teaches Us. Follow The Qur'aan And Sunnah.

So If Muslims Follow These Then Theres No Bad News For Him, He Will Enjoy The Joyful Moments Under The Grave ( The Aalam E Arwah, World Of Spirits ) Till The Doomsday (The Qaya'maah) Occurs,
The Time Period Is All Dependent To The Type Of Human, A Good Spirit Will Face Very Short Time But A Bad Spirit Will Live A Long Life With Painful Time That "NO ONE CAN BEAR"

At Judgment Day S/He Will Be Lifted Up For The Judgment Day And Will Be Answerable For All His Actions...

May ALLAH Forgive Us For ALL Our Bad Actions..
Amen